# Adjective that means "to be on a bed?"

Tags: word-request

Example sentence:

> When he opened the door, he found a bandaged, [...] Mary.

I thought the word was *bed-stricken* but I was wrong.

Comment: Perhaps "bedridden" if she cannot leave the bed due to her injuries.

Comment: Also [bedbound](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/bedbound) - considerably less common, but [gaining traction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bed-ridden%2Cbed-bound&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbed%20-%20ridden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbed%20-%20bound%3B%2Cc0) (especially as an AmE *hyphenated* usage). I'd say that's because ***-ridden*** is becoming a fairly "dated" suffix today.

Comment: The word **abed**, might work, though it is not common at all.

Comment: @relaxing Ah! I confused the word bedridden with bed-stricken. Should I delete this post to save face?

Comment: *Bed-stricken*, *bedridden* and *bedbound* all imply fairly long-term confinement to bed. To indicate merely the fact of being in bed, without implying that the state is either temporary or enduring, we'd use an ordinary locative PP, *in bed*: "... he found a bandaged Mary in bed." *Abed* is an obsolete version of the same phrase, and must follow the noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others in the comments have mentioned

> bedbound
>   bedridden

are the usual adjectives to describe the situation when someone is confined to a bed.  Both usually imply a medical affliction as the cause.

> *noun***bound**
>   *housebound*

is also used to describe people who are confined within their house, e.g. due to old age.